# “covering an area of 6000 square metres.”

Tags: participles, participle-clauses

I came across this introductory text of the Terracotta Army and found the bold part a bit weird, can you use the participle “covering” that way?

It reads better, to me, if I rephrase it to “*This pit, covering an area of 6,000 square metres, was discovered in April 1976.”*  Are there any differences in these two sentences?

> Located 66 feet (20 meters) to the north of Pit 1 at the eastern end, Pit 2 is in an "L" shape. **This pit was discovered in April 1976, covering an area of 6000 square metres.**

Comment: Presumably you already know / suspect what the difference is, or you wouldn't have produced the revised version in the first place. The original is "invalid", (or stylistically poor, depending on your point of view), because the relative clause *(covering an area of 6,000 square metres)* is too far away from its referent *(This pit)*.

Comment: Your gut is not leading you astray. A better version of the sentence is, “This pit, discovered in April 1976, covers an area of 6000 square metres.” My version does shift the meaning a bit though, rendering the date of discovery as parenthetical, an “Oh, by the way.” And note that its structure parallels the previous sentence’s, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can't put it into words. The original one reads so “weird”, as I said in my question. 
Is it a grammatically valid sentence? or just “ stylistically poor”?

Comment: *...or stylistically poor, **depending on your point of view**.* Obviously if someone else's "point of view" is that the text is actually ***ungrammatical***, they're not going to accept other people (such as me) saying it's just ***subjectively bad style*** rather than ***objectively bad syntax***. But you definitely shouldn't copy it, so it shouldn't make any difference ***why*** you need to avoid it yourself.

Comment: The claused headed by **covering** is not so far away from its referent that it is too far away, and there's no chance that a reader would get confused and think "how can April 1976 be said to cover an area?"  Instead, you could understand the slightly postponed clause to be a reflection of the fact that it took some time to discern just how large the pit was; its full extent was not immediately apparent when it was first discovered.

Comment: @TimR: So that's a *third* possible position. I'm sure at least *some* people would unequivocally assert that the cited usage is ungrammatical. I don't go that far, but I don't accept there are *ever* contexts where a competent writer would use it. You seem to be saying you think there are contexts where it could actually be the ***right*** choice. Whatever - surely learners would do better to avoid it. It's not a matter of whether it could be misunderstood - to me it's just clumsy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with the general rule you're espousing, that you don't want to have  the nonfinte clause so far detached from what it modifies that the listener or reader might lose track of the syntax, and you don't want anything intervening to introduce ambiguity into the syntax, so there's doubt about what is being modified. But the current example doesn't violate that rule, IMO. It seems natural and idiomatic to me, and I hear that nonfinte clause as relating to the *discovery of the pit*, not just the pit per se.  The pit was found *to be covering* 6000 square meters.

Comment: @TimR: I think your last two sentences there actually endorse *my* position! I'd say it's strongly implied by *The pit was found to be covering 6000 square meters* that ***the existence of the pit was already known [long] before its extent was appreciated***. That reading contradicts the *actual* text, which strongly implies that both the existence and the extent were discovered in April 1976. (So perhaps there ***is*** scope for ambiguity, after all! :)